# How to print the specific date between two dates using golang?

Tags: date, go

I'm retrieving the `start_date` and `end_date`  from the db. Through `for` loop I will print the dates between like (Monday, Tuesday,... Soo on). I have also a same situation I print the dates between two dates but I want if I'm retrieving the data of Monday then it will show me the coming Mondays not all days. If I'm retrieving the data of the Tuesday then it only show me the Tuesday dates I have tried a code but it will print all days how will I get the expected output

code:-

```
func GetSchedule(c *gin.Context) {
response := ResponseControllerList{}
selected_day:= "Monday"
conditions := bson.M{"day":selected_day}
data, err := models.GetSchedulingListing(conditions) 
for i := range data {
    start_date := data[i].StartDate
    end_date := data[i].EndDate
    start_time := data[i].StartTime
    end_time := data[i].EndTime
    start_working_hours := time.Unix(start_time,0).Format("3:04PM")
    end_working_hours := time.Unix(end_time,0).Format("3:04PM")
    days := time.Unix(end_date,0).Sub(time.Unix(start_date,0)).Hours() / 24
    for i := 1; i <= int(days+1); i++ {
        // fmt.Println(i)
        // fmt.Println(start_date)
        fmt.Println(time.Unix(start_date,0).Format("Monday, 01-02-2006")+" "+ start_working_hours+" "+ end_working_hours)
        start_date = start_date + 86400
    }
}
dataCount, err := models.GetRecordsCount(config.ScheduleCollection, conditions)
if err != nil {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.FailureCode,
        config.FailureFlag,
        config.FailureMsg,
        nil,
        nil,
    }
} else {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessMsg,
        data[0],
        dataCount,
    }
}
GetResponseList(c, response)
}
```

See in condition I pass Monday but it return all days in output:-

Output-

```
Tuesday, 05-01-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
Wednesday, 05-02-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
Thursday, 05-03-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
Friday, 05-04-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
Saturday, 05-05-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
Sunday, 05-06-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
..Soo on up to end date
```

Expected output If I give condition That only Monday then:-

```
Monday, 05-07-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
...Next Monday date
```

If I give in condition Tuesday then

```
Tuesday, 05-01-2018 8:00AM 10:00AM
... next Tuesday date
```

Database

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"day" : "Monday",
"start_date" : NumberLong(1525132800),
"end_date" : NumberLong(1527638400),
"start_time" : NumberLong(9000),
"end_time" : NumberLong(16200),
"added_on" : NumberLong(1526442426),
"occurence" : "repeat",
"updated_on" : NumberLong(0)
}
{
"_id" : 2,
"day" : "Monday",
"start_date" : NumberLong(1525132800),
"end_date" : NumberLong(1527638400),
"start_time" : NumberLong(27000),
"end_time" : NumberLong(34200),
"added_on" : NumberLong(1526442426),
"occurence" : "repeat",
"updated_on" : NumberLong(0)
}
{
 "_id" : 3,
 "day" : "Tuesday",
 "start_date" : NumberLong(1525132800),
 "end_date" : NumberLong(1527638400),
 "start_time" : NumberLong(27000),
 "end_time" : NumberLong(34200),
 "added_on" : NumberLong(1526442426),
 "occurence" : "repeat",
 "updated_on" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

Comment: so basically you want to print the day names (you will need location for this) between two timestamps? sorry i don't get quite well the problem....

Comment: @victor Actually in this there is a start_date and end_date and i have to print the day data according to the condititon see in my code condition is  on Monday soo i want to see the record between start_date and end_date of only  for monday if i select tuesday then the record is for tuesday only. Understand?

Comment: so you have three parameters: start, end, and a day of week. So you process for each week day that is in between the begins and ends? You are asking how you could get "those" days?

Comment: I just want to print thay days with there dates which is in conditions @victor see in condition i types there monday then i Want to retrieve the data of monday only if tuesday then retrieve the data of tuesday

Comment: ok... now we are getting to something concrete... you want to print days of the week between two dates that satisfies a given predicadate? For example if the predicate is "monday" you inly print mondays.. if the predicate is "friday" then print only fridays?

Comment: Yeah @victor nbw you got what i want can you help me?

Comment: Sure thing stack... that is the purpose of this place.. to help others and by the way improve yourself by helping others...

Comment: @victor can you write something for me that can help me to solve this problem i stucked here from three days but there is no success :(

Answer (score 2):

I can leave you some hints about how you can archieve the goal of :

> get the days of the week between two dates that satisfies a given
>   predicadate?

Follow this code snippet, hope it can give some clues about how to archieve the desired goal.

This is more straight ahead:
https://play.golang.org/p/-zQYNWtgHZ2

This has a little more design decisions:
https://play.golang.org/p/qHlsCoQkSiQ

- Please do notice that you should implement you day of week
  filtering/selection like the **func** `admitAllWeekDays`.
- Also notice that the day of week has its implementation based on as an integer.

Leaving the answer aside, Slack, what you need is to organize a little bit your code.. i see that you are struggling a little more that the problem itself that you present as the question.

Comment: I appriciate your answer but now I fedup to do this again again and agian from three days.

Comment: sorry, i will try to improve a little bit the comments... meanwhile try to bear with me...

Comment: Its okay I think i need rest

Comment: @stack i'm glad for you then! don't forget to mark this as correct answer if you think that resolves your question